# Wine made from fruits other than grapes

Tags: blessing, grapes-wine, kiddush

Wine can be made out of any fruit. What is the bracha of wine made from fruit other than grapes? May this wine be used for kiddush?

Comment: I haven't checked but I expect the bracha would be shehakol given that the bracha for wine is 'pri ha'gafen', and other fruits aren't fruits of the vine. I know that other liquids can be used for kiddush. One can even make kiddush on bread.

Comment: This is just a word game with the word "wine". You can fermented apple juice but we usually call that cider not wine.

Comment: @DoubleAA but in this case word games might be exactly the answer, if you call it "chamar medina"

Comment: @DoubleAA, this is an English language centred view.

Comment: @CarstenS Indeed as "wine" is an English language word.

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chayim 204:1) says:

> ועל שכר תמרים ... מברך שהכל...
>
> ... And on date liquor... One makes the Shehakol blessing

I'm not sure what you'd define as 'wine' (per DoubleAA's comment), but this seems to be saying that fruit-based alcohol is Shehakol, when it's not grape-wine.

As for using it for kiddush/ havdala, it would have the same rules as any *chamar medina* (assuming it fits the bill and is popular enough to be called that), meaning it can be used for kiddush during the day or for havdala, but not for kiddush at night, though only if wine isn't available (Orach Chayim 289:2).

Comment: Wine isn't just preferable - as the referenced halachah states, *chamar medina* may only be used if wine is not available ("*matzui*"). I internally cringe when i see people making kiddush on schanpps at a kiddush when there's wine right there!

Comment: @TheotherotherAlan I didn't know that! Shkoyach